# Why are my coordinates returning as a string?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, leaflet, geojson

Below is our schema to return coords from our leaflet map.

```
 //Schema
 name: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
 trim: true
 },
 properties:{

 },
 coordinates: [Number]
,
email: {
type: String,
unique: true,
required: true,
trim: true
},
```

This is code to returns coords on click to our form. But its not returning as a number but are returning as a string. How can we make the input be a number in our form?. We tried several things but none worked.

```
map.on('click', onMapClick);
  L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
  map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    var latLng = e["popup"]._latlng;
    var form = document.querySelector('#popupForm');
    form['coordinates'].value = latLng['lat'] + ', ' + latLng['lng'];
```

Comment: "We tried several things" - what were they?

Comment: Form field values are *always* strings.

Answer (score 0):

Convert input type as an number.You can use two different input with type as an number for latitude and longitude.Then grab lat and lng and set values in inputs.

HTML form

```
<form id="popup-form" method='POST' action='/spotForm'> 
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='spotName'>Name</label>
            <input type='number'class='form-control' name='lat' placeholder='Latitude'>
            <input type='number'class='form-control' name='lng' placeholder='Longitude'>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Add Spot Data</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    var latLng = e["popup"]._latlng;
        var form = document.querySelector('#popup-form')
        form['lat'].value = latLng['lat'];
        form['lng'].value = latLng['lng'];
});
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: We appreciate your input! Unfortunately this did not do the trick- our value was still returned as a string and we also found we could not push to our schema afterward. Our end goal is to have our inputs go into the database as a number and not a string.

Comment: i thing you can convert the coordinates to Number on server side before insert in db